# count the arrays in a large array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote the following code but when the rows are large it is slow

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([
                   [1,2],[1,2],[2,3],
                   [1,2],[2,3],[5,2]])
d={}
for l in array:
    t = tuple(l)
    if t in d:
        d[t]+=1
    else:
        d[t]=1
print(d)
```

result:

```
`{(1, 2): 3, (2, 3): 2, (5, 2): 1}`
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```python
elements, counts = np.unique(array, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

In your case, `elements` will be

```
[[1, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [5, 2]]
```

and `counts` will be
`[3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy library be like

```
final_count={}
for lst in [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in array)]:
     final_count[tuple(lst)]=array.count(lst)
```